# Google Geocode Components two countries

Tags: api, google-maps, geocoding

How is it possible to filter the results of the Google Geocode API and the use of the components parameter for **two** (or more) countries, *without issuing another request*.

Example:

- `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&components=country:DE,AT&address=wien`
  gives zero result, as there is no Wien in Germany and the AT after the comma is ignored
- `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&components=country:AT,DE&address=wien`
  is ok, because there is an Wien in Austria
- `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&components=country:AT|country:DE&address=wien`
  gives zero results, as the two component filters are outruling each other

Is there something in the documentation that I overread that makes it possible, or can't I make it at all?

### Edit

I tried a workaround with setting the merged bounds of Germany and Austria, but that just weighs the results and not filters them, so I got a result which I didn't want with `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&components=bounds:55.058,17.161|46.372,5.866&address=new%20york`. In this case I want a ZERO_RESULTS status.

Comment: Have you figured out if this is possible?

Comment: @kaciula Nope! Unfortunately

Comment: Have you found a solution or workaround for this in the meantime? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @Pim Unfortunately not. But I was not working on this issue in the meantime. Too much too do on other plans.

Comment: Ok too bad. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I don't think it is possible. From docs about Component Filtering: _The Google Geocoding API can return address results restricted to a specific area. The restriction is specified using the components filter. A filter consists of a list of component:value pairs separated by a pipe (|)._ **Only the results that match all the filters will be returned.**

Comment: @AntoJurković I'd say about this: then the Google Geocode API is rubbish.

Comment: This is not possible. There is an [open issue here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4233) for that feature.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible.  Please vote up [issue #4233](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4233) if you want to see this happen.

For time being I can suggest three possible workarounds, none of them perfect:

1. Make multiple requests and merge the result sets manually.  This will give the best accuracy, but is obviously the slowest.
2. Use the manually merged bounds trick in HerrSerker's question, then manually filter out results where the `short_name` of the `address_components` element with a `types` of `country` is not in your list of countries.
3. Drop the component filter entirely and include "Austria OR Germany" in your search string.  Again, you will want to manually filter the results.